# Make a string output as a list in Pwm

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, python-3.5

How can I make a string output a list? (Probably very simple, I know)

I have looked through all of google, and *NONE* of the solutions worked.

**My code:** (it's a bit paraphrased)

```
import Pmw
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

console = Pmw.ScrolledText(...some arguments...)
console.pack(...some arguments...)

console.settext(os.listdir("."))

root.mainloop()
```

**Outputs:** `file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` in the Pmw.ScrolledText box.

What do I need to do to make the output look like the following?

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

My thanks to you.

Comment: console.settext('\n'.join(os.listdir(".")))

Comment: What is that? Can you make that understandable please?

Comment: Like that ^ you can always join string in an array by using '<repeating string>'.join(<array>)

Comment: Wait. Are you on windows? Its safer if you use `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: I think I've got it, but why should I use `\r\n`? Yes, Windows.

Comment: Read on my young friend: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n And welcome to programming, you're going to have fun here, i guarantee it

Comment: @spikespaz good on you.  Just keep up your inquisitiveness and when stuck (after thinking/searching for a while and couldn't find solution elsewhere) continue to phrase clear, concise questions like this, help will be on your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the items in the `list` returned by `os.listdir()` using a new-line character:

```
filenames = os.listdir('.')
text = '\n'.join(filenames)
console.settext(text)
```

Comment: Good god, this site is amazing! The responses are so quick! Now I just have to wait 8 minutes to accept your post as the answer. Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can use  **\n** (new line character). for example:
print 'file1.txt\nfile2.txt\nfile3.txt'

You can find more information here - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html